# My code using Beautiful Soup 4 does not display anything. What's wrong?

Tags: python

I am trying to do an assignment which is accessing school link and displaying all the phone numbers listed in it using beautiful soup.

The code below is what I got done so far.  It runs with no problems, but the print function does not print the phone numbers.  I think I may have a problem with the class selectors and the arguments for them, but i am not sure

```
import requests, bs4, re

res = requests.get('http://catalog.tri-c.edu/about/important-phone-numbers/')
res.raise_for_status()

catalogPage = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'html.parser')

selectors = ['.column1''.column2''.column3''.column4']

for selector in selectors:

  elements = catalogPage.select('.column1''.column2''.column3''.column4')

  for element in elements:

    phoneRegex = re.compile(r'([0-9])\d\d\W\S\d\d\W\S\d\d\d')

    match = element.getText(phoneRegex)

    if match == None:
      continue

    print("Phone Number: ", match)
```

Comment: Print out `selectors` and you will see.

Comment: @KlausD. Tried that, nothing comes up.

Comment: Show us the output of `print(selectors)` then.

Comment: @KlausD. Not sure what you mean, but nothing comes up.  It compiles it and displays nothing.

Comment: Then there is something wrong beyond the code you are showing us.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what the issue is? Have you done any debugging?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I updated your code and added some comments so you understand better what was wrong:

```
import requests, bs4, re

res = requests.get('http://catalog.tri-c.edu/about/important-phone-numbers/')
res.raise_for_status()

catalogPage = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'html.parser')

# Your version of selectors (this is actually a 
# list of only one concatenated string):
selectors = ['.column1''.column2''.column3''.column4']
# This prints: ['.column1.column2.column3.column4']
print(selectors)

# You missed the commas between the selectors, 
# this will give you an actual list:
selectors = ['.column1','.column2','.column3','.column4']
# This prints instead ['.column1', '.column2', '.column3', '.column4']
print(selectors)

for selector in selectors:
    # You want to select one selector at the time only:
    elements = catalogPage.select(selector)

    for element in elements:
        phoneRegex = re.compile(r'([0-9])\d\d\W\S\d\d\W\S\d\d\d')

        # The regex is not an actual argument to element.getText().
        # At first, you want to get the text from the element node.
        # At second, you want to check whether it matches your phone
        # regex.
        match = phoneRegex.match(element.getText())

        # In python, one compares None objects with the `is` operator.
        if match is None:
            continue

        print("Phone Number: ", match.group())
```

Answer (score 2):

I found 3 errors which I'v fixed below:

1. You `selectors` must be written as a list, each item must have a comma separating it from the next.
2. Your regex pattern wasn't correct
3. To use regex to find text in bs4, you must specify that in the parameters `element.find_all(text = phoneRegex)`

**Here's the corrected code:**

```
# This must be a list
selectors = ['.column1','.column2','.column3','.column4']

for selector in selectors:

    # This will return a list for each selector
    elements = catalogPage.select(selector)


    for element in elements:

        # Fix the regex pattern
        phoneRegex = re.compile(r'[0-9]{3}\-[0-9]{3}\-[0-9]{4}')
        match = element.find_all(text = phoneRegex)

        if not match:
            continue

        # Otherwise
        print(f"Phone Number: {match[0]}")
```

Comment: Nested data structures are very much a thing in web scraping @AnsBekk 

Answer (score 1):

```py
import pandas as pd


df = pd.read_html("http://catalog.tri-c.edu/about/important-phone-numbers/")[0]

df.to_csv("data.csv", index=False)
```

Output: [view-online](http://www.sharecsv.com/s/09a9c421833cfcf070cb13e596d8fe0b/data.csv)

[image]

`pandas` can be accessed as a `list`:

```py
print(df["Eastern Campus"].to_list())
print(df["Metropolitan Campus"].to_list())
print(df["Western Campus"].to_list())
print(df["Westshore Campus"].to_list())
```

Output:

```
['216-987-2226', '216-987-2256', '216-987-2070', '216-987-4325', '216-987-2567', '216-987-6000', '216-987-6000', '216-987-6000', '216-987-0595', '216-987-6000', '216-987-6000', '216-987-6000', '216-987-2045', '216-987-2230', '216-987-2343', '216-987-2013']     
['216-987-4225', '216-987-4311', '216-987-4550', '216-987-4325', '216-987-4913', '216-987-6000', '216-987-6000', '216-987-6000', '216-987-4292', '216-987-6000', '216-987-6000', '216-987-6000', '216-987-4610', '216-987-4290', '216-987-4253', '216-987-6137']     
['216-987-5227', '216-987-5256', '216-987-5550', '216-987-4325', '216-987-5575', '216-987-6000', '216-987-6000', '216-987-6000', '216-987-5656', '216-987-6000', '216-987-6000', '216-987-6000', '216-987-5428', '216-987-5079', '216-987-5683', '216-987-5204']     
['216-987-5588', '216-987-3888', '216-987-3908', '216-987-4325', '216-987-2067', '216-987-6000', '216-987-6000', '216-987-6000', '216-987-3888', '216-987-6000', '216-987-6000', '216-987-6000', '216-987-5929', '216-987-5732', '216-987-5902', '216-987-3536']
```

`bs4` usage as i see there's no reason to use `regex` at all:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

r = requests.get("http://catalog.tri-c.edu/about/important-phone-numbers/")
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')


column1 = [item.text for item in soup.findAll("td", class_="column1")]

print(column1)
```

Output:

```
['216-987-2226', '216-987-2256', '216-987-2070', '216-987-4325', '216-987-2567', '216-987-6000', '216-987-6000', '216-987-6000', '216-987-0595', '216-987-6000', '216-987-6000', '216-987-6000', '216-987-2045', '216-987-2230', '216-987-2343', '216-987-2013', '216-987-3075', '216-987-3075', '216-987-3075']
```

Comment: Cool, but this doesn't use bs4!  I also do not want to export.  I just want all the numbers to populate using the regex argument.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: I downvoted since the answer neither addresses the actual problem in the code nor comes with any explanation.